# Validation through JFormattedTextFields in Java

Tags: java, swing, validation, jformattedtextfield

I want to have two textfields which will have the following validations

1. Both should be Integers
2. The value in one textfield should be a integer multiple of other

I have used two JFormattedTextFields to this. This is what i have done till now

```
NumberFormat updateFormat,sampleFormat;
updateFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
updateFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
updateFormat.setParseIntegerOnly(true);
sampleFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
sampleFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
sampleFormat.setParseIntegerOnly(true);
javax.swing.JFormattedTextField jFormattedTextField1 =new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField(updateFormat);        
javax.swing.JFormattedTextField jFormattedTextField2 = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField(sampleFormat);
```

With the help of this my first part is complete
Now I am stuck with the second part, i.e. jFormattedTextField1 value should be a Integer multiple of jFormattedTextField2. I think I need to customize my NumberFormat by extending it. But How should I do that? Please help me out

Comment: crossposted http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/376023/1618434#post1618434

Comment: @mKorbel: thanks for the warning. This will be noted if he asks questions again here in the future.

Comment: You should specify what you want to happen on violating either rule  with respect to, e.g. truncation, navigation, notification, etc.

Comment: @trashgod For both the rule I initially wanted a notification but I think I can manage with truncation also

Comment: You're right to deliberate among alternatives; see also this [article](http://www.amberweinberg.com/even-good-programmers-need-to-review-the-basics/).

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels. Sorry If I violated any rules by crossposting in different forums. I did this because there are different people in different forums and they will have different answers to my questions, which will help me solve out my problems in the best possible way. But If its against the forum rules I will follow it and wouldn't crosspost in future

Answer (score 5):

Also consider using an [`InputVerifier`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html), as discussed in [*Validating Input*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification).

Answer (score 2):

NumberFormat won't work for the "second" part of your problem since the limitation isn't a *data format* limitation but rather a *data value* limitation. I think that you will need to use a DocumentFilter for the second part. To learn more on how to use these, please have a look here: [Implementing a Document Filter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter)

Comment: you pointed out a good point that I have to put a data value limitation and NumberFormat won't work. I had a look at Document Filter u posted but thought the answer given trashgod to more easy to use. Thanks for the reply